# Set a "minimum" chars input in a inputbox throw javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a javascript code working ok, so if the inputbox is blank it tells you, I also need to put a MINIMUM number of chars (for example minimum 10 characters should be inputted)...

PLEASE can somebody help me with this, here is the code:

```
var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        var flag = 0;
        if(title == "")
        {
            requiredfields = requiredfields + '<li><?php echo JText::_('MUST PROVIDE TITLE');?></li>';
            document.getElementById('title').focus();
            flag = 1;
        }
```

and here is what I added after this but it doesn't want to work... I mean it doesn't give any errors or something.. it just doesn't react..

```
if ( title < 10 )
        {
            requiredfields = requiredfields + '<li><?php echo JText::_('MUST PROVIDE MINIMUM 10 CHARS');?></li>';
            document.getElementById('title').focus();
            $('title').addClass("invalid");
            flag = 1;
        }
```

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property:

```
if (title.length < 10) {
    requiredfields = requiredfields + '<li><?php echo JText::_('MUST PROVIDE MINIMUM 10 CHARS');?></li>';
    document.getElementById('title').focus();
    $('title').addClass("invalid");
    flag = 1;
}​
```

Comment: Hi, you was very helpful yesterday, can I please ask you one more thing, to the same code, how can I validate the input if it contains a certain word in this code? ... so teoreticaly it's something like :

`code`
IF (title == "this word") {}​
`code`

Comment: You can use `indexOf`. So in your case `if (title.indexOf("word") != -1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(title == "" && title.length < 10) {
   //do your stuff
}
```

or

```
if(title == "") {
   //do something if title is empty
}else if(title.length < 10) {
   //do something if length is under 10 characters
}else{
   //do something if not empty and over 10 chars
}
```